# jQuery changing the size of a div on click

Tags: jquery, html, css, web

My code can be found here:

http://jsfiddle.net/wQyMh/

and here:

```
<button id="button" onclick="fade()" id="button">Shrink</button>

<div id="fadeScreen">
    <div class="fadePart"></div>
</div>
```

So basically, I want the div to show and hide when the button is clicked, but the simple jQuery is not working. What is up with it?

Comment: Your calling a function called fade but that function doesn't exist in your script.

Comment: Just curious - why have you specified the ID twice?

Answer (score 2):

All you need is a [`toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) but first you need to set `.fadePart` to hidden

```
$(document).ready(function () {   
    $("#button").click(function () {    
        $(".fadePart").toggle();
    });    
});
```

And your markup contains `onclick=fade()` where `fade()` doesn't exist in your code remove `onclick` from `<button>`

[<kbd>Fiddle Demo</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/wQyMh/12/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this to show/hide div.

```
$('button').on('click', function(){
    if(!$(this).hasClass('clicked')){
        $('#fadeSreen').hide();
        $(this).addClass('clicked')
    } else {
        $('#fadeSreen').show();
        $(this).removeClass('clicked')
    }

});
```

Or this.

```
$('button').on('click', function(){
        $('#fadeSreen').slideToggle();
})
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/wQyMh/7/)

Answer (score 0):

You have a few problems in your code:

1. Your #fadeScreen element is 'hiding' your button (z-index wise...), and the 'click' applies on it, instead of on your button (git it a background-color, and you'll see it hides the button).
2. Don't "Double bind" the 'click' event, instead just do this:

   $("#button").click(function(){
           $(".fadePart").toggle();
       });

Answer (score 0):

Use this, `Don't provide more than one id attribute inside the tag`

HTML

```
<button id="button">Shrink</button>

        <div id="fadeScreen">
            <a class="fadePart"></a>
        </div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#button").click(function(){  
    $("a").toggleClass('fadePart');
  });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wQyMh/16/)

Answer (score 0):

**Your fiddle contains some errors. I have corrected the errors here...**

```
    <button id="button" id="button">Shrink</button>    
    <div id="fadeScreen">
        <div class="fadePart"></div>
    </div>

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('button').click(function(){}
            $('#fadeScreen').toggle();
        });
    });
```

> refer the following fiddle - [fiddle1]: http://jsfiddle.net/hCzLG/